# Root of a polynomial and its reciprocal modulo a prime

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Fix a large prime $p$ and let $k \leq 10 \sqrt{p}$. What are the $z\in \mathbb{F}_p$ that satisfy $$f(z) = f(1/z) = 0,$$ where  \begin{align*}f(z) &= (2-z) \cdots (2k-z)  + (-1)^{k+1} \cdot 3 \cdots (2k+1) \\
& = \left(\prod_{j=1}^k (2j - z)\right) + (-1)^{k+1} \prod_{j=1}^k (2j+1) ?\end{align*}

Comment: What exactly is the product (is it over integers or even integers between $2$ and $2k$)?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you for your question, yes indeed..I added an equation to clarify.

Comment: So $z=-1$ is an answer (may be not unique)?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, when $k$ is even, $z = -1$ is a solution. I don't really know much more than this besides a sporadic case and that there are no solutions for small (fixed) $k$.